# Event click button cannot direct to another page

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I am testing an event handler
When I click the button nothing happens. Why does the code not work?

This is my code:

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('button')
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.location.href = 'https://www.youtube.com'
})
```

```html
<div class="container-login100-form-btn">
  <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
    <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
    <button class="login100-form-btn" id="button" type="submit" "> Enter </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show the HTML. The code should work if there is only ONE button with id="button"

Comment: the is the html code:<div class="container-login100-form-btn">
      <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
       <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
       <button class="login100-form-btn" id="button" type="submit"">
         Enter
       </button>
      </div>
     </div>

Comment: You have an extra `"` after `"submit"`

Comment: Please put the actual HTML in the question.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when you click?

Comment: remove the extra `"` and make it `type="button"`

Comment: oh yeaa my bad sorry

Answer (score 0):

Your code works if you remove the extra `"`. I also suggest you change to type="button"

The reason the code does not connect here at SO, is when the target does not want to be in an iFrame.

This code works as you can see, as long as there is only ONE button with id="button"

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('button')
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.location.href = 'https://www.bing.com'
})
```

```html
<div class="container-login100-form-btn">
  <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
    <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
    <button class="login100-form-btn" id="button" type="button"> Enter </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want more than one site and one button, use delegation and remove th ID from the buttons

```js
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.matches(".login100-form-btn")) { 
    window.location.href = tgt.dataset.url;
  }  
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
    <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
      <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
      <button class="login100-form-btn" type="button" data-url="https://bing.com"> Bing </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
    <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
      <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
      <button class="login100-form-btn" type="button" data-url="https://testlink.org/"> TestLink </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let btn = document.getElementById('button')
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
   location.assign("https://www.youtube.com");
})
```

Comment: I don't think this makes any difference. See https://linuxhint.com/href-vs-assign-in-javascript/

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
let btn = document.getElementById('button')
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    location.href = "https://www.youtube.com/"
})
```

Comment: There's no difference between `location.href` and `window.location.href`.

Comment: Its only YouTube link that is not working. Other links are working

Comment: How do you know that, it's not in the question. That sounds like YouTube is blocking it.

Comment: But when i tried another link instead of YouTube it worked. But when i try YouTube link it shows YouTube refused to connect

Comment: But you can go to the same YouTube link by putting the URL in the browser's address bar?

Comment: Does changing from `window.location.href` to `location.href` really fix it for you?

Comment: No it won't. You are the one who corrected my mistake. But when i put YouTube link it didn't work. Then i tried putting stackoverflow link. Then it worked. I dont know why that happened

Comment: When i Google the issue about YouTube i saw people facing similar problems.

Comment: All of this about youtube vs other sites should be comments on the original question, it has nothing to do with this answer.